# Trying to create Vue app, but getting "SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier" when running command in terminal

Tags: node.js, vue.js

I have been working in AngularJS for a while now and I decided to try out Vue. I installed Vue using `npm install -g @vue/cli` in my terminal using Node version 6.4.0. After the installation was complete I tried creating a new app using `vue create <name of app>`. It's during this seemingly simple step that I am getting hung up with this error:

```
/Users/jonalden/.nvm/versions/node/v6.4.0/lib/node_modules/@vue/cli/node_modules/open/index.js:16
const wslToWindowsPath = async path => {
                               ^^^^
SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
    at Object.exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:76:16)
    at Module._compile (module.js:528:28)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:565:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:473:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:432:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:424:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:483:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/jonalden/.nvm/versions/node/v6.4.0/lib/node_modules/@vue/cli/node_modules/@vue/cli-shared-utils/lib/openBrowser.js:9:14)
    at Module._compile (module.js:556:32)
```

I have tried downgrading Node to a previous version and reinstalling Vue with Yarn but both were unsuccessful. One thing throwing me off here is the line `wslToWindowsPath`, which is especially weird since I am on a Mac.

Comment: It seems you're using an ancient version of node. Try upgrading node to at least version 12.

Comment: Looks like you need at least Node version 8.11.0 `Currently, as of early 2019, to get the best results with Vue CLI, the minimum version of Node required is 8.11.0+, but you can kind of get by with 8.9 if you really have to.` take [from here](https://subscription.packtpub.com/book/web_development/9781789950342/1/ch01lvl1sec11/setting-up-vue-cli-3-on-our-system)

Comment: Node version was the issue, thanks! I had actually downloaded the latest version of Node earlier, but I was running the older version for my job. I just ran `nvm install 12.0.0` and it worked like a charm.

Answer (score -2):

I had the same problem. I've done this :

```sh
sudo rm -rf ~/.nvm
```